# Display CSV row number from fields in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I currently have a large scale application that takes a CSV file and renders the details into various PDFs. When naming the output files, I want to display the row number associated with the row in the CSV so all the PDFs appear in order. I cannot seem to get the row number from the CSV file?

```
function safeFileName($filename)
    {
    return str_replace(array("\\", "/", ":", "*", "\"", "?", "<", ">", "|"), "_", $filename);
    }

$outputFilename = safeFileName($ticket['size_title']."_".str_pad((int)
ROW_NUMBER, 
, STR_PAD_LEFT).'_'.$ticket['ticket_code']);
```

Comment: where ROW_NUMBER is the row number, padded with up to three 0's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're reading the lines with `fgetcsv()`. You'll need to manually track the row number inside your `while` loop like they do with `$row` in [Example 1 on the fgetcsv documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

For writing the file name, I'd use [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$outputFilename = sprintf("%s_%03d_%s", safeFileName($ticket['size_title']), 
         $row, $ticket['ticket_code']);
```